# Lorentz transformation of the spinor fields

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, spinors

I have been reading the Srednicki's QFT textbook (available online at https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html) and in Chapter 34 the left and right-handed spinors are discussed. There is a step in the logic that I simply cannot follow.

The discussion starts with a left-handed spinor field transforming according to:
$$
U(\Lambda)^{-1}\psi_a(x)U(\Lambda) = L_a^{\; \;b}(\Lambda)\psi_b(x) .
$$

Now, considering an infinitesimal Lorentz transformations:
$$
U(1+\delta\omega) = I + \frac{i}{2}\delta\omega_{\mu\nu}M^{\mu\nu}
$$
and
$$
L_a^{\; \;b}(1+\delta\omega) = \delta_{a}^{\; b} + \frac{i}{2}\delta\omega_{\mu\nu}(S_L^{\mu\nu})_a^{\;\,b}
$$
where $M^{\mu\nu}$ are the generators of the Lorentz transformation, and $S_L^{\mu\nu}$ is the generator for the Lorentz transformation of the spinor. Substituting these infinitesimal transformations into the equation above we get:
$$
[\psi_a(x),M^{\mu\nu}] = -i(x^\mu\partial^\nu - x^\nu\partial^\mu)\psi_a(x) + (S_L^{\mu\nu})_a^{\;\,b}\psi_b(x)
$$
We can make use of the rotation generator $M^{ij} = \epsilon^{ijk}J_k$ and set $x^\mu=0$ to simplify the equation, which leads to:
$$
\epsilon^{ijk}[\psi_a(0),J_k] = (S_L^{\mu\nu})_a^{\;\,b}\psi_b(0)
$$
I am more or less happy with all the steps above. However, now the author argues that $S_L^{ij} = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{ijk}\sigma_k$, because the (2,1) representation includes spin 1/2. I do not understand how spin 1/2 leads to to $S_L^{ij} = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{ijk}\sigma_k$.

Even if I plug the result directly into the equation it does not seem to work:
$$
\epsilon^{ijk}[\psi_a(0),\frac{1}{2}\sigma_k] = \epsilon^{ijk} \frac{1}{2} \left[ \psi_a(0)\sigma_k -\sigma_k\psi_a(0) \right] \neq \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{ijk}(\sigma_k)_a^{\;b}\psi_b(0)
$$
where I used that for the (2,1) representation $J_k = \sigma_k/2$. What am I missing here?

Comment: 1. What are the $\sigma_k$? Pauli matrices? Isn't $S^{ij}_L = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{ijk}\sigma_k$ by definition then? 2. What does the (2,1)-representation have to do with any of this? The left-handed spinor representation is usually denoted as the (1/2, 0)-representation. 3. The $J_k$ are operators on the infinite-dimensional space of states, they certainly cannot be equal to any multiple of the (presumably) finite-dimensional $\sigma_k$. I thus do not understand what you're trying to do in your last paragraph.

Comment: The author uses a different notation for the representations. You are right that the spinor representation is usually denoted as (1/2,0). In the last paragraph, I was just trying to make sense of the $S^{ij}_L$. I don't think it is by definition, or at least Srednicki doesn't make it look that way.

Comment: It's not true that $J_k= \sigma_k/2$. The $J$'s act on the same infinite dimensional Hilbert space that the $\psi_a(x)$ fields act on. The $\sigma$'s act on the two dimensional space of the indices on the Weyl spinor.

Comment: Oh I see, but then I have no idea how to show that $\epsilon^{ijk}[\psi_a(0),J_k] = (S_L^{\mu\nu})_a^{\;\,b}\psi_b(0)$ is satisfied for that particular choice of $S^{ij}_L$ ..

Comment: Below (34.7) he simply states the "convention" that the spin 1/2 matrices on the RHS of (34.6) are the Pauli matrices, and in the previous chapter he references QM angular momentum results you're supposed to just know, so you're supposed to see this as an obvious extension of the non-relativistic result where one shows the total angular momentum $J$ is $J = L + S$ and one constructs the spin matrices for arbitrary spin, and this book is simply relying on the fact that $S_L$ is a SO(3) spin 1/2 rep.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, $S^{ij}_L = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{ijk}\sigma_k$ comes from choosing the (1/2,0) representation for the $SU(2)\times SU(2)$ group. That means choosing (in Chapter 33) $N_i = \sigma_i /2$ and $N_i^\dagger = 0$, which leads to $J_i = \sigma_i /2$ and $K_i = i\sigma_i/2$ leading to $S^{ij} = \epsilon^{ijk}J_k = \epsilon^{ijk}\sigma_k /2$. And the commutation relation in the Q has nothing to do with this choice. Is that correct?