# Spin and scale dimension of canonical spin-1/2 fields in (1+1)d

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions, wick-theorem, bosonization

I am reading the book "Non-perturbative methods in 2 dimensional quantum field theory" by Abdalla, Abdalla and Rothe and have some questions about the Chapter 2.4 "Bosonization of Massless Fermions".

Earlier in the book (2.20 & 2.21) they show that the zero mass two-point functions look like
$$\begin{align}
D^+(x)&=\langle \phi(x)\phi(y) \rangle=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\ln[(i\mu x^++\epsilon)(i\mu x^-+\epsilon)] \tag{2.20}\\
\tilde{D}^+(x)&=\langle \phi(x)\tilde{\phi}(y) \rangle=\frac{1}{4\pi}\ln\frac{i\mu x^++\epsilon}{i\mu x^-+\epsilon} \qquad x^\pm=x^0\pm x^1.
\tag{2.21}\end{align}$$
These two-point functions act under a Lorentz transformations like $D^+(\xi')=D^+(\xi)$ and
$\tilde{D}^+(\xi')=\tilde{D}^+(\xi)+\frac{\chi}{2\pi}$ (see 2.24).
Then they compute an arbitrary correlator (see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKznF.png)) of bosonized Fermi fields $$\psi^{\alpha,\beta}(x)=:\exp(i\alpha\tilde{\phi}+i\beta\phi(x)):$$
$F(x,y)$ acts under Lorentz transformations like $$F(\Lambda x,\Lambda y)=F(x,y)+n\frac{\alpha\beta}{\pi}\chi.$$ So far so good.

[image: Definition of F(x,y)]

Now my questions:

1. They conclude that the field $\psi^{\alpha,\beta}(x)$ transforms as
   \begin{align}
   U(\Lambda)\psi^{\alpha,\beta}(x)U^{-1}(\Lambda)=e^{\frac{\alpha\beta}{2\pi}\chi}\psi^{\alpha,\beta}(\Lambda x)
   \end{align}
   Why is that the case? What is $U(\Lambda)$? Some kind of  unitary operator?
   Then they go on and call $\frac{\alpha\beta}{2\pi}$ in the exponent the spin $s$. What has this to do with the spin? (I know that in (1+1)d there is no real spin because there are no rotations and spin is a matter of convention.)
2. Then they do this same business with dilatations $x \to e^\lambda x$ and find the transformation law
   \begin{align}
   U(\lambda)\psi^{\alpha,\beta}(x)U^{-1}(\lambda)=e^{\frac{\lambda}{4\pi}(\alpha^2+\beta^2)}\psi^{\alpha,\beta}(e^\lambda x).
   \end{align}
   and call $\frac{\alpha^2+\beta^2}{4\pi}$ the scale dimension $\Delta_{\alpha,\beta}$. Same questions as above.
3. What is the scale dimension $\Delta_{\alpha,\beta}$ of the canonical spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ field? Is it also $\frac{1}{2}$ like the spin? They say that the case $\alpha=\beta=\pm\sqrt{\pi}$ corresponds to a canonical spin $\frac{1}{2}$ field. (I have no prior experience in conformal field thories.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let me try to go through the questions and answer what I can:

---

1. 

> What is $U(\Lambda)$? Some kind of unitary operator?

Yes! A Lorentz transformation on scalar fields only transforms the coordinate $U(\Lambda) \phi(x) U(\Lambda)^{-1} = \phi(\Lambda x)$. However, for higher-spin fields it also mixes the components of the field. After rotating 180$^\circ$, a spin-up particle might be spin-down after all (see for example [Lorentz transformation of the spinor fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/552684/276737)).

In this case, there is only one compenent. However, the field can still be scaled by Lorentz boosts and it scales differently for different parameters $\alpha,\beta$. They call $\frac{\alpha\beta}{2\pi}$ the spin of the field, because it specifies the behavior of the field under boosts (as in 3+1 dimensions).

> They conclude that the field $\psi^{\alpha,\beta}(x)$ transforms as ... Why?

As I understand it, they deduce this from the transformation behavior of $F(x,y)$ as follows:
Because $U(\Lambda) |0\rangle = |0\rangle$, it holds that
$$
  \langle0| \psi^{\alpha,\beta}(x_1) \cdots \psi^{\alpha,\beta}(x_n) \psi^{\alpha,\beta}(y_1) \cdots \psi^{\alpha,\beta}(y_n)|0\rangle = \langle0| U(\Lambda) \psi^{\alpha,\beta}(x_1) U(\Lambda)^{-1} \cdots U(\Lambda) \psi^{\alpha,\beta}(x_n) U(\Lambda)^{-1} U(\Lambda) \psi^{\alpha,\beta}(y_1) U(\Lambda)^{-1} \cdots U(\Lambda) \psi^{\alpha,\beta}(y_n) U(\Lambda)^{-1} |0\rangle
$$
Assuming that $\psi^{\alpha,\beta}$ scales a certain way under Lorentz transformation, we make the Ansatz
$$
  U(\Lambda) \psi^{\alpha,\beta}(x) U(\Lambda)^{-1} = e^{f_{\alpha,\beta}} \psi^{\alpha,\beta}(\Lambda x).
$$
We want to find the number $f_{\alpha,\beta}$. From the above equation, we have
$$
  e^{F(x_1, .., x_n, y_1, .., y_n)} = e^{2n f_{\alpha,\beta}} e^{F(\Lambda x_1, .., \Lambda x_n, \Lambda y_1, .., \Lambda y_n)} = e^{2n f_{\alpha,\beta}} e^{F(x_1, .., x_n, y_1, .., y_n)} e^{n \frac{\alpha\beta}{\pi} \chi},
$$
where we used the transformation behavior of $F$. From this equality, we can conclude $f_{\alpha,\beta} = -\frac{\alpha\beta}{2\pi}$. I'm not sure where the wrong sign comes from, if you have an idea please let me know.

---

2. 

> Then they do this same business with dilatations $x \mapsto e^\lambda x$ and find the transformation law ...

I'm sure this works similar to before. Again, the transformation of $F$ will be the crucial indicator here. Are they computing it in the book?

> What is $U(\lambda)$?

As before, operators that scale the space can act differently on different fields (they might grow stronger). But I am also not well-versed with such things.

---

3. 

I'll let you know when I find some good introduction conformal scaling for fields of different spin. But I can't say much from the top of my hat.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Part 1. of my question has been settled after comparing my (1+1)d problem to the (3+1)d case (which I know from the QFT Lecture Notes of David Tong). 

$F(x,y)$ transforms as $F(e^\lambda x,e^\lambda y)=F(x,y)-n(\alpha^2+\beta^2)\frac{\lambda}{2\pi}$ under dilatations.
We demand that the correlation function is invariant under Lorenz transformations. But why can or should we do it for dilatations?

Comment: This should come from the Lagrangian/Action. If the action $S = \int dx~ \mathscr L(x)$ of the model is invariant under dilations, or at least changes only by a factor, then also the solutions of the theory will be the same (the action is still minimized for the same solution, but the minimum has a different value). The vacuum is then invariant under such a transformation.   

For massive particles, this is not the case because the kinetic term and mass term transform differently. For massless fields, dilations generally are such a symmetry.